# ConstraintValidatorContext stores previous nodes when it shouldn't

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation

I have this class

```
@HasNose
@HasMouth
public class Person {

    String fieldA;
    String fieldB;
    // getters and setters

}
```

Now the custom annotations validator look something like this

```
// validator of @HasNose
@Override
public boolean isValid(Object object, 
                        ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    // some tests that determine there is an error
    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Some message")
            .addNode("fieldA")
            .addConstraintViolation();

}
```

and

```
// validator of @HasMouth
@Override
public boolean isValid(Object object, 
                        ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    // some tests that determine there is an error
    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Some message")
            .addNode("fieldB")
            .addConstraintViolation();

}
```

Running this produces the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'fieldA.fieldB' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.processConstraintViolations(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:148)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:101)
at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:722)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:154)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:107)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:155)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

For some reason "ConstraintValidatorContext" is concatenating both fields. Debugging shows that the attribute "propertyPath" comes already filled out with "fieldA".
I thought it should be at the root level per constraint validator doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my own problem, I was using hibernate-validator-4.2.0.BETA2. Switching to hibernate-validator-4.2.0.FINAL solved the issue.

Lesson to learn: keep your libs updated...

Comment: you should even upgrade to 4.3.0.Final. Several performance improvements in this version. Also a good idea to close the question.