# can @Email and spring custom validation coexists?

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator, customvalidator

I need to validate Email and password while creating an account using web services. I am using Spring REST controller and plan to use @Email(hibernate validator) annotation for email id validation.For Password validation I have to write custom validator by implementing Validator interface.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Email(message =AccountErrorCodes.ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VALIDATION)
    private String emailId;

    private String password;
```

For password writing the own validator

```
@Autowired
private PasswordValidator passwordValidator;

@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(passwordValidator);
}
```

It looks like both cant coexist. When I try to validate EmailId spring calls passwordValidator but fails to validate Email. I expect the failure due to incorrect Email id. When I disable the custom validator I get the required error message.

Looks like I am missing something. Do I need to do something to make it work? or it is not supported? If not supported Can I call Hibernate validator directly from spring custom validator to avoid writing my own validation for email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of injecting your custom validator in your controller, make a special `@Password`  annotation for it that uses this as a validator. Remove any constraint logic from controller and do it all on your DTO class. Something like this:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordValidator.class)
public @interface Password {
    String message() default "{Invalid password}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

You will find loads of tutorials for custom annotations that use your own made validators. Hope that helps.

Comment: By Writing our own custom annotations can I still use Binding Result object that Spring provides which returns multiple error messages?

Comment: Also Is there anything that I am not doing correctly?

Comment: I am not sure if you can. I wouldn't recommend to try anyway. It's not good practice to have validation logic in the controller, or even worse in two different places. You should validate your DTO with `@Valid` annotation only in your method signature.

Comment: Yes I could return multiple error messages I just found the post on stackoverflow(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059961/constraintvalidatorcontext-stores-previous-nodes-when-it-shouldnt) that seems to work well.

Comment: Just double checking ..the scenario that I want to use "can @Email and spring custom validation coexists?" is not possible?

Comment: I believe it's not. Unless you do some ugly hack for it.

Answer (score 0):

You asked :
By Writing our own custom annotations can I still use Binding Result object that Spring provides which returns multiple error messages?

Yes .

You can make your own custom annotations for any type .
For example :

#### Phone Number

```
    @Phone
    @NotEmpty
    private String phone;
```

Now make a java file :

#### Phone.java

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PhoneValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Phone {
 
     
   String message() default "{Phone}";
     
   Class<?>[] groups() default {};
     
   Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
      
}
```

And a class to provide validations measures :

#### PhoneValidator.java

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class PhoneValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Phone, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Phone paramA) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String phoneNo, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(phoneNo == null) {
         return false;
        }
        
        //Validate phone numbers of format "1234567890"
         if (phoneNo.matches("\\d{10}")) return true;
         
        //validating phone number with -, . or spaces
        else if(phoneNo.matches("\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4}")) return true;
        
         //validating phone number with extension length from 3 to 5
        else if(phoneNo.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}\\s(x|(ext))\\d{3,5}")) return true;
        
         //validating phone number where area code is in braces ()
        else if(phoneNo.matches("\\(\\d{3}\\)-\\d{3}-\\d{4}")) return true;
        
         //return false if nothing matches the input
        else return false;
    }
    
    

}
```

Now in :

#### message_en.properties

Include :

```
#Custom validation annotation
Phone=Invalid format, valid formats are 1234567890, 123-456-7890 x1234
```

By this way , you will succesfully get a custom validator .

#### BindingResult

will catch the error and get the message from the properties file .

Hope this helps .